# SwiftUI - Preview canvas gives Coordinated install error

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to run the Landmark sample for the SwiftUI, but getting following error

> Error Domain=IXErrorDomain Code=29 "A coordinated install for com.example.apple-samplecode.Landmarks is already pending." UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Unhandled reason for code: 29 in domain IXErrorDomain, FunctionName=+[IXAppInstallCoordinator(IXSimpleInstaller) _beginInstallForURL:consumeSource:options:completion:]_block_invoke, SourceFileLine=143, NSLocalizedDescription=A coordinated install for com.example.apple-samplecode.Landmarks is already pending.}

Enviorment: Catalina Beta + Xcode Beta

Comment: Have you tried resetting the Simulator via the Hardware >> Erase all content and settings?

Comment: As per my understanding preview canvas doesn't need a simulator. However, I tried this but it did not worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please have a look of [SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_11_beta_release_notes?language=objc) known issue

## Known Issues

> - Previews may fail or update incorrectly when switching between files.
>     (50841287)
>
>   => Workaround: Add a newline to the end of the active file, then click "Resume" in the banner that appears.
> - watchOS previews might fail if you select a physical phone that’s
>     paired with a watch as the run destination from the Scheme pop-up
>     menu. (50861269)
>
>   =>Workaround: Select a watchOS simulator while working with previews.
> - Previews don’t appear in the canvas for private and fileprivate
>     structures that conform to PreviewProvider. (47011316)
>
>   => Workaround: Remove the private or fileprivate access control from your
>     conforming type.
> - Previews might take several seconds to update when switching devices
>     in the run destination selector the first time. (47562171)
> - Previews might temporarily show the incorrect device chrome when
>     switching devices using the run destination from the Scheme pop-up
>     menu. (49496647)
> - The canvas doesn’t support focus. (50275735)
> - Undo is unavailable in the canvas. (49651153)
>
>   =>Workaround: Bring the source editor into focus and perform the undo
>     there.
> - The insertion indicator only shows on the topmost item for repeated
>     content such as content in a List or ForEach view. (50244112)
> - Xcode 11 beta doesn’t support working with SwiftUI in a project
>     configured to use UIKit for Mac.
> - When you launch Xcode on macOS 10.15 beta, the required packages
>     installer might display erroneously. (51080815)

## Note:

I know, Everyone wants to work with a new layout design pattern but still, `SwiftUI` framework is not stable.